# How to give border-color to a row in TableView with QT Quick Contol 2.0?

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qtquickcontrols

Table1

```
            Item {
                id: control
                TableView {
                    id: table1
                    delegate: Rectangle {
                        color: control.selected === row ? "pink" : "white"
                        border.color: control.selected === row?"lightblue":"transparent"
                        border.width: 2
                        Text {
                            text: display
                            color: "black"
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Table2

```
    TableView{
        id :tableView
          headerDelegate:Rectangle{
                color : "transparent"
               Text
                {
                    text: styleData.value
                }
           }

       rowDelegate: Rectangle {
           color : styleData.selected ?  "pink" : "white"
           border.color: styleData.selected ?"lightblue":"transparent"
       }
       itemDelegate: Rectangle{
           color : "transparent"
           Text {
                color : "black"
                text: styleData.value
            }
       }

         style: TableViewStyle{
             backgroundColor : "transparent"

         }
    }
}
```

effect

[image]

It is easy to make with rowDelegate at QtQuick Controls version 1.0 .
I have no idea for setting border-color for row item while row selected.
It seems border-color can only be set for each item in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it with other four rectangles finally :)
like this:

```
Rectangle { anchors.top: parent.top; height: item_table.borderWidth; width: parent.width; color: isSelect()?borderColor:"transparent"}
Rectangle { anchors.bottom: parent.bottom; height: item_table.borderWidth; width: parent.width;  color: isSelect()?borderColor:"transparent"}
Rectangle { anchors.left:  parent.left; height: parent.height; width: item_table.borderWidth; color: borderColor; visible: (isSelect()&&column === 0) }
Rectangle { anchors.right: parent.right; height: parent.height; width: item_table.borderWidth; color: borderColor; visible: (isSelect()&&column === tableView.columns - 1) }
```